# How to group by multiple attributes on children, and then count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a User model that has many Awards.

The Award class has :type, :level and :image attributes.

On a User's show page I want to show their Awards, but with some criteria. User.awards should be grouped by both type and level, and for each type-level combination I want to display its image, and a count of the awards.

I'm struggling to construct the queries and views to achieve this (and to explain this clearly).

How can I group on two attributes of a child record, and then display both a count and attribute (i.e. image) of those children?

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure this out because of the complicated mix of active record objects, arrays and grouped arrays.

Anyway, incase this is useful for anyone else

Given a User has many Awards, and Award has attributes `:type`, `:level`, `:image`.

```
for award in @user.awards.group_by{ |award| [award.type,award.level] }.sort_by{|award| [award[0][0], award[0][1]]}
  puts "#{(award[0][0]).capitalize} - Level #{award[0][1]}"  # e.g. Award_Name - Level 1
  puts award[1].first.image #outputs the value of award.image, i.e. the image url 
  puts award[1].count  #counts the number of grouped awards
end
```

A bit fiddly! Maybe there are ways to optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you're using you have to build a custom SQL query using a `GROUP BY` on type and level:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY users.type, users.level
```

(Postgres has a special interpretation of the `GROUP BY` so check the document of the database you're using).

To write it in Rails read the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

For the count you'll have to do it in a second step (Ruby could do it using the `size` method on the Array of ActiveRecord object the query will return you).